# Lazy loading SVG with CRA

Tags: reactjs, svg, lazy-loading, create-react-app

I want to lazy load SVGs with CRA, but damn I'm stuck and need your help.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const LoadIcon = (name) => lazy(() => import(`../icons/${name}.svg`));

const SvgComponent = ({ icon }) => {
  const Icon = LoadIcon(icon);
  console.log("Icon ", Icon);
  return <Icon />;
};
```

It's worth to mention that I did tried what official CRA suggest(without lazy load tho):

```
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from "../icons/myCoolSvg.svg";
```

But this kind of destructuring doesn't work with lazy.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without redundant components:

```
const SomeImage = lazy(async () => ({
    default: (await import("./some_image.svg")).ReactComponent,
}));
const SomeComponent = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <SomeImage />
    </Suspense>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

for destructing to work with lazy, you can default export it from separate file as below

```
// Middle Component
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from "./github.svg";

export default Icon;
```

and then call it lazily in your component

```
const MiddleComponent = lazy(() => import(`./MiddleComponent`));
const Svg = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <MiddleComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Check demo here -
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lazy-svg-loading-gi2ru

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the svg to a react component with [svgr](https://react-svgr.com/playground/) and then do lazy loading on the react component version.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7211